# stop activity indicator when all data has been fetched from server

Tags: react-native

I'm getting activity indicator after 20 posts as the offset number is set to 20 and after each scroll its loading more content but I want it to stop loading (Activity Indicator) when reached at the end of the data and there is no data to fetch.

Here is all the default states:

```
this.state = {
      data: [],
      dataProvider: new DataProvider((item1, item2) => {
        return item1.ID !== item2.ID;
      }),
      isLoading: false,
    };
```

Here is the render of the component:

```
render(){

    if( !this.state.data.length ) {
      return(
      <ActivityIndicator
        style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}
        size='large'
        color='#0A80FE'
      />
      );
    }

return(
      <>
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
          <RecyclerListView
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            onEndReached={() => {
              this.getData();
             //(ignore this as this is required for recyclerlist view)
              this.setState({}); 
            }}
            onEndReachedThreshold={1000}
            dataProvider={this.state.dataProvider}
            rowRenderer={this.renderItem}
            renderFooter={this.renderFooter}
          />
        </View>
      </>
    );
```

Here is the getData function:

```
getData = () => {

    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return;
    }

    this.setState({
      isLoading: true
    });

      const url = 'some url?offset=' + this.state.data.length;
      fetch(url).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          this.setState({
            data: this.state.data.concat(responseJson.posts),
            dataProvider: this.state.dataProvider.cloneWithRows(
              this.state.data.concat(responseJson.posts)
            ),
          })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        }).finally(() => {
          this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
          })
        })
  }
```

Here's renderItem function:

```
renderItem = (type, item ) => (
    <ListItem
      containerStyle={{height: 120}}
      title={item.title}
      subtitle={item.author.name}
      leftAvatar={avatar}
      bottomDivider
    />
  );
```

And here is renderFooter function:

```
renderFooter = () => {
    return !this.isLoading
      ? <ActivityIndicator
          style={{ marginVertical: 10 }}
          size='large'
          color='#0A80FE'
        />
      : <View style={{ height: 60 }}>
          <Text style={{color: '#ccc', textAlign: 'center', paddingVertical: 10,}}> You've reached at the end of the posts.</Text>
        </View>;
  };
```

renderFooter always sets to loading even if I reached at the end of the posts resulting in an unending activity indicator

Comment: Check if `responseJson.posts` is less than the number of items you're grabbing, and if it is, then you know if you've exhausted the results. So if you're grabbing 20 posts at a time and you see the API returned 17 posts, then that must be the end of the data.

Comment: In `renderFooter`, use `this.state.isLoading` rather than `this.isLoading`